# <a> tag with background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a background image in an  tag working. I am firstly trying to get a modification of an example I found off the web working but it is not. Code as below:

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
  a {
    background-color: blue;
    background-image: url("./linkedinlogo.png");
    display: block;
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
  }
</style>
<a href="https://pagedart.com"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

The background colour displays but not the background image. Edge, chrome, Firefox tried. image and HTML file is same directory. Filename spelling checked and intellisense lists file when ./ is typed.
Tried removing background colour to see if helps but doesn't.

Kind regards,
Tim

Comment: What does the browser console / network panel say, do you see a 404 for the image URL in either of those?

Comment: This should work, assuming your path is correct. (Though it will only show the top left 32px square, if you have a large image. Which may appear invisible if your image has the same colour background as the page or is transparent)

Comment: Resp., if you put `<img src="./linkedinlogo.png">` into the body, does the image show then? If not, then either your path _is_ wrong, or the image file itself is somehow broken.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/sohovudali/1/edit?html,output — The code works fine if I change the URL to one that resolves to an image. You must have code the URL wrong (despite what intellisense says). Debug it with the Network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: I have looked at my code and output further and found that DBS is spot on (not sure how to give you kudos) and I would mark as answer if I could for a comment. My image is transparent in the top left 32px square. Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working as expected. Check this out

```css
a {
    background-image: url("https://www.edigitalagency.com.au/wp-content/uploads/Linkedin-logo-icon-png.png");
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
  }
```

```html
<a href="https://pagedart.com"></a>
```

Comment: your CSS is different from the CSS on the question.

Comment: There is no difference, I made it display: inline-block and removed background-color. If you want, I can add it back and it will still work as expected.

Comment: "There is no difference" and "I changed the `display` property" in the same comment hahaha

Comment: What's the problem if this serves the purpose?

Comment: Also, without changing something, how can you expect the result?

Comment: You said "It is working as expected" which implies nothing needed changing. Maybe you meant "This is working as expected:" ?

Comment: Thank you Abin but I dont know which change you made fixed the issue.

Comment: I have removed the background-color, and replaced `display: block` with `display: inline-block`. Those are the only two changes.

Comment: The addition of 'background-size: contain;' seems to have fixed the issue as it shrinks the image so it shows in top 32px square. My file path syntax was correct in the end(where I thought error probably was).

Comment: Marked as answer as 'background-size: contain' fixes issue as alternative to adjusting pixel size.

Answer (score -2):

Add The Following Code:

```html
    <html>
<body>
<style>
  a {
    background-color: blue;
    background-image: url("./linkedinlogo.png");
    display: block;
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
  }
</style>
<a href="https://pagedart.com">
    <img src="imgSrc"></img>
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The don’t want an image, they want a background image.

Comment: i've written it as background image as thats the css property. The end goal is a picture link but using the css background image property.

Comment: adding <img src="./linkedinlogo.png"> to within <a> tag as suggested does show the image. This suggests to me that the path is probably ok unless the requirements of using url() are different to using src